# How to make those 2 colours equal....?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sxd.png)

So, I'm doing this Amazon clone application using flutter and want to make those two colours equal like same colours.
Please Give me a solution to make them equal colours

```
appBar: AppBar(
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            // Status bar color
            statusBarColor: Colors.red,
          ),
```

I have tried this code in main.dart file but its not responding so, i'm expecting a good solution to make them same colour

Answer (score 0):

- Add this line in your main method

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red, //bottom bar color
      statusBarColor: Colors.red, //top bar color
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```